# Angular 6 view not updating, even with ChangeDetectorRef, ngZone, and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

In my **component.ts**, I have a loop that converts WAV audio data to MP3:

```
for (var i = 0; i < samples.length; i += sampleBlockSize) {

  let sampleChunk = samples.subarray(i, i + sampleBlockSize);
  var mp3buf = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(sampleChunk);
  if (mp3buf.length > 0) {
      mp3Data.push(mp3buf);
  }

  this.convertedPercent = Math.floor( ( i / samples.length ) * 100);
  console.log('convertedPercent: ' + this.convertedPercent);
}

console.log('This is where the HTML view jumps from 0% to 100%');
```

In my **component.html** I have code that displays what percentage of the audio has been converted so far:

```
<p>Conversion is {{ convertedPercent }}% complete</p>
```

**While the conversion is happening, it logs the correct conversion percentage to the console in real time**, however the view stays stuck at 0% complete.  Once the loop ends, it instantly jumps to 100%.

I have tried:

- `this.cd.detectChanges();`
- wrapping the line which changes the value of `convertedPercent` in `zone.run()`
- wrapping the line which changes the value of `convertedPercent` in `requestAnimationFrame()`

What on Earth should I try next?

Comment: I suspect you need to give a fraction of time for each iteration, try setTimeout() maybe. https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/how-to-set-a-delay-between-foreach-loop-iteration-solved/88932/2

Comment: Actually, I tried that too and it didn't help :-(

Comment: It would be easier to give fix if you can create sample demo in stackblitz

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your issue?

Comment: @newwebdev22: No, I did not.  I believe that Suresh's answer is correct - that it is impossible to achieve this without moving the conversion logic into a web worker.

Answer (score 2):

As we know, Javascript is Single Threaded. If you perform heavy computation, your main thread will be blocked and won't be freed until it completes. May be you can try with Observables, with is async operation browser will process it based on priority.

**Component:**

```
convertedPercent$ = new Subject<any>();
convertedPercent$.next(this.convertedPercent);
```

**Template:**

```
<p>Conversion is  {{ convertedPercent$ | async }}% complete</p>
```

Comment: I tried this and the result is similar.  The view only displays "Conversion is % complete" while the loop is running, and then when it finishes it changes to "Conversion is 100% complete".  I think you may be right about the main thread being blocked, though.  That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You can move this conversion logic to web-workers (a separate thread) and update the status to main thread using window.postMessage

Comment: That makes sense.  I will try to implement that and will report back here with the results.  Thanks for your help!